# Django: Python global variables overlap, even for separate runs

Tags: python, django, global-variables

I have a Django (so Python) program with a global variable:

```
g_variable = []
```

I use this is several functions where I also change the value:

```
my_function()
    global g_variable 
    g_variable.append(some_value)
```

That worked great until I started calling the program multiple overlapping times - in Django that means that I loaded the webpage multiple times quickly. I expected that the global variable would only be global within each individual run, but that is not the case. The values that are appended to g_variable in one run can be seen in the next run.

To me this means that I now have to pass this variable around to all my functions:

```
my_function(non_g_variable)
    non_g_variable.append(some_value)
    return non_g_variable
```

called with

```
non_g_variable = my_function(non_g_variable)
```

Is that correct? Before I change all my code I just want to make sure that I haven't missed something. It will add a lot of extra lines and return calls.

Comment: What is this variable doing? There's almost certainly a better way of doing it.

Comment: It's an object that represents a webpage, essentially all the elements and attributes, parent-child relationships, etc. This is used throughout my code.

Comment: I'm going to need to see a real example. It seems like you are building up your page in a very unusual and non-Djangonic way. Usually you'd just call a single view function to build up the context, and pass it to a template for rendering.

Comment: It's not a Django thing - It's not the html for the template that I am building. It's a webpage that I am given, and which I then have to parse. Once it is parsed I then have to access it in various ways. I therefore have helper functions like is_it_am_image() or does_it_contain_a_link(). These functions access the global variable which essentially contains the webpage structure. I guess I could do it like a new class. Seems like it would involve as much rewritting, but maybe is more proper.

Answer (score 3):

You should probably redesign your code to get rid of the global variable, as other answers and comments say. Something along the lines of:

```
class WebpageStructure(object):
    def __init__(self, html):
         # parse the html
         self.structure = self.parse(html)
    def contains_link(self):
         # figure it out using self.structure
         return ...

# in the view(s)
webpage = WebpageStructure(html_to_parse)
if webpage.contains_link():
    ...
```

There are however options:

1. If your code always runs in a single thread you can fix the problem by setting `g_variable` to `[]` between each run. There is probably one top-level function (a Django view function perhaps?) that always marks the start of each run. You should re-initialize the `g_variable` in this top-level function.
2. If your code runs multi-threaded, you cannot use a normal global variable. Concurrent threads will update the same global variable.

   Regarding 1 and 2: To run a Django site in a single thread, use `manage.py runserver --nothreading` for the development server. If you host your site in apache/mod_wsgi, you can control this using [daemon mode](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide#Delegation_To_Daemon_Process). Note that you can run multiple single-threaded side-by-side processes. Using a global variable will work in that scenario, since the processes are isolated.

   If possible your code should work in any process/thread model.
3. If your code runs multi-threaded and you really want to avoid passing around the `g_variable` list you can use thread-local variables. Documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.local) and [here](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/4973c90ce9e6/Lib/_threading_local.py).

Example:

```
import threading
threadlocal = threading.local()

def mydjangoview(request):
    # In your top-level view function, initialize the list
    threadlocal.g_variable = []
    # Then call the functions that use g_variable
    foo()
    bar()

    # ... and then I guess you probably return a response?
    return Response(...)

def foo():
    threadlocal.g_variable.append(some_value)

def bar():
    threadlocal.g_variable.append(some_other_value)
```

Other links:

- [Why is using thread locals in Django bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227180/why-is-using-thread-locals-in-django-bad)
- [What is so bad with threadlocals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920053/what-is-so-bad-with-threadlocals)

Comment: Always +1 when someone tries to explain threading and locals.

Answer (score 2):

That's how global variables work in Python. The global state persists for as long as the web application server keeps running.

A common solution would be to put your functions in a class, store the per-request state on that class and use a new instance of that class for each request.

Answer (score 1):

Using global variables, except for constants, is almost always error-prone, and often produces code that is difficult to read. Therefore, it is the wrong concept. Receiving an argument, modifying and returning it is much more explicit about what a function is doing than on-the-fly modification of a global variable.

So yes, I would go ahead and implement the receive-modify-return concept or wait until someone has a special "djangonic" solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problems can be resolved by implementing a [cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/) - a simplified explanation of a cache is - a global variable across a *session*.